# New Column from String in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~col1, ~col2, 1, 2)
```

Now I want to create a column. I have the name of the new column in a string. It does work like this:

```
df %>%
    mutate("col3" = 3)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
```

But it does not work like this:

```
newColumnName <- "col3"
df %>%
    mutate(newColumnName = 3)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
   col1  col2 newColumnName
  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1     2             3
```

How do I create a new column that gets its name from a string in an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `!!` with the definition operator `:=` as mentioned [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), to set a variable name as the column name.

> := supports unquoting on both the LHS and the RHS

```
library(dplyr)
newColumnName <- "col3"
df %>% mutate(!!newColumnName := 3)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
   col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
```