# Merging two df in r replace missing values

Tags: r, merge

I want to match two similar dataframes in R. Both dfs have partially the same variables and a key (id), which contain missing values:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- as_tibble(list(id = seq(1:6),
                      v1 = c(1, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA),
                      v2 = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, NA),
                      v3 = c(1, 0 , 1, 1, 1, NA)))
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id    v1    v2    v3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    NA     1
2     2     0    NA     0
3     3    NA     0     1
4     4     1     0     1
5     5     0     1     1
6     6    NA    NA    NA

df2 <- as_tibble(list(id = seq(1:6),
                      v1 = c(1, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                      v2 = c(1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1),
                      v4 = c(0, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA)))

df2
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id    v1    v2    v4
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0
2     2    NA     0     1
3     3     0     0     0
4     4     1    NA    NA
5     5     0     1    NA
6     6     1     1    NA
```

I'd like to merge those into one df that looks like this:

```
     id    v1    v2    v3    v4
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1     0
2     2     0     0     0     1
3     3     0     0     1     0
4     4     1     0     1    NA
5     5     0     1     1    NA
6     6     1     1    NA    NA
```

So far I've tried all kind of joins from dplyr, but somehow I am not getting it.

Comment: If the merge is performed using the id column, What are the rules for combining the matching columns v1 and v2?  Do you take the average, sum, the value from df1 or from df2?

Comment: For the desired outcome in column v2 row 6 it says NA, should this be 1?

Comment: Dave2e: It should be whatever value is valid, either from df1 or df2.

Comment: MKa: You are right, fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better answer, comparing to my first one:

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(~ coalesce(.[1], .[2]))

## A tibble: 6 x 5
#      id    v1    v2    v3    v4
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     1     0
# 2     2     0     0     0     1
# 3     3     0     0     1     0
# 4     4     1     0     1    NA
# 5     5     0     1     1    NA
# 6     6     1     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: very nice, does exaclty what i've asked for, even when adding more variables and with dfs of different lenght. can you explain, what exactly are you indexing within `coalesce()`?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::coalesce` on the shared columns after splitting using the common names. Then *map* "loop" through dfs with more than one column and `mutate` using `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by='id') %>% 
        split.default(gsub('.[xy]','',names(.))) %>% 
        map_dfc(~if(ncol(.x)==1) .x else 
                mutate(.x, !!sym(gsub('.x','',names(.x)[1])):=coalesce(!!!syms(names(.x))))) %>% 
        select(-contains('.'))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
       id    v1    v2    v3    v4
     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1     1     1     1     1     0
  2     2     0     0     0     1
  3     3     0     0     1     0
  4     4     1     0     1    NA
  5     5     0     1     1    NA
  6     6     1     1    NA    NA
```

Here a simple example illustrates what `sym` and `syms` do to each variable contains .x and .y columns, e.g. here `v1`. `coalesce` support tidy dots features hence we use `!!!syms`.

```
df_sub <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by='id') %>% select(v1.x, v1.y)
# . represents df_sub
nm <- gsub('.x','',names(df_sub)[1])
nms <- names(df_sub)
df_sub %>% mutate(!!sym(nm) := coalesce(!!!syms(nms)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  v1.x  v1.y    v1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     0    NA     0
3    NA     0     0
4     1     1     1
5     0     0     0
6    NA     1     1
```

`sym` and `syms` these functions take strings as input and turn them into symbols, then we use `!!` and `!!!` to unquote them. We use `:=` since we need to use a string as column name inside mutate, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162309/new-column-from-string-in-dplyr/56162351#56162351). Read more about `sym`, `syms`, `!!` and `!!!` [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with the `sym` code? It's pretty dense

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, similar to @utubun's approach using `bind_rows` and `summarise`.

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  # convert NaN to NA (if required)
  mutate_at(vars(-id), function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x))
```

Comment: works fine, might I ask, why the mean function works?

Comment: You could potentially use `sum` but the `sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)` will give you 0 whereas `mean(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)` will give you NaN.